# White Space over notification area in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

We are having an application with three activities.

1) startup Activity which doesn't have any actionbar or navigation drawer (splash)
2) Main Activity  with action bar 
3) Another Activity with action bar

The theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

We are facing a strange issue on lollipop phone that white space is shown in notification area without any icons (completely blank) in startup activity and other activity. No issue on Kitkat or earlier phones.

Also, this problem is not encountered with MainActivity having Actionbar and navagation drawer

Any idea what could be wrong? will be happy to provide more details if requires.

You can see screenshot: http://imgur.com/1K9LbWi

Comment: put color xml and style xml for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

This was the issue which somehow went into values-v21/styles.xml, removing it solved. Thanks all of you for answering.

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/myNavigationColor</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your status bar is in white color so you can not see any notification icon. Please change your status bar color with style.xml.
Open your style.xml and change color of colorPrimaryDark attribute.

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```